# Disallow global anonymous bind with cn=config

Tags: openldap

With slapd.conf you could globally disable anonymous binding and require authentication with the following static directives:

```
disallow bind_anon
require authc
```

How can I achieve the same global settings, but using the new cn=config live configuration method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not that quanta's ACLs are a bad thing, but to answer your question:

> ldapmodify
>   dn: cn=config
>   changetype: modify
>   add: olcDisallows
>   olcDisallows: bind_anon
>   -
>
> dn: olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config
>   changetype: modify
>   add: olcRequires
>   olcRequires: authc

Please be aware that ldapmodify is sensitive to (trailing) spaces, so a straight copy paste won't work (and may not authenticate your properly either). Also, the dn you use will need write access to the cn=config db.

Answer (score 11):

Variation on the same theme, I tried it out, works:
[LDAP security tips at SysadminTalk](http://www.sysadmintalk.net/forums/thread-2571.html)

Summary:

1) Create a file, let's call it `disable_anon_frontend.ldif` with the following content:

```
dn: olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config
add: olcRequires
olcRequires: authc
```

2) Create another file called `disable_anon_backend.ldif` with the following content:

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
add: olcRequires
olcRequires: authc
```

3) Then on the server, modify the LDAP by issuing the following commands:

```
sudo ldapmodify -Q -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f disable_anon_frontend.ldif
sudo ldapmodify -Q -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f disable_anon_backend.ldif
```

4) Check by executing the following anon query: `ldapsearch -x -LLL -H ldap:/// -b dc=example,dc=domain,dc=com dn` (use your `dc=...` settings as applicable).

If you see the error message below, then anonymous access has been successfully disabled:

```
Server is unwilling to perform (53)
Additional information: authentication required
```

Good luck!

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! While this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thanks, you're absolutely right, I edited my answer as recommended.

Answer (score 1):

I've not tested but try something like this:

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
add: olcAccess
olcAccess: to attrs=userPassword 
    by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" write 
    by self write 
    by * none
olcAccess: to dn.base="" 
    by users read 
    by * none
olcAccess: to * 
    by dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" write 
    by * none
```

Comment: Thanks, this is how I am currently doing it per database. However, my question was how to do it globally.