# How to disable anonymous read on OpenLDAP using cn=config

Tags: openldap

I am a newbie with openldap 2.4 and I need to restrict read access to anonymous. Actually, if someone write `ldapsearch -x -H ldap://myipaddrr` he can see all entries of my HDB database.

How can I solve this using cn=config (dynamic configuration). By default there is a lot of olcAccess setup...

thank you

Comment: Maybe the [manual](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html) offers some insights?

Comment: Of course I have read the manual twice but the offical document is too complicated...

Comment: Maybe there is some similar question on serverfault http://serverfault.com/questions/325912/disallow-global-anonymous-bind-with-cn-config

Comment: @NoNoNo thank a lot ! It could be useful in a first time...

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution.

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcDisallows
olcDisallows: bind_anon
-

dn: olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcRequires
olcRequires: authc
```

Now, when someone try to read data with `ldapsearch -x -H ldap://myipaddrr` , he can't and receive this error message:

```
ldap_bind: Inappropriate authentication (48)
    additional info: anonymous bind disallowed
```