# why does anonymous user could access userPassword attribute of OpenLDAP?

Tags: openldap, access-control-list, anonymous

Here is my ACL, openldap is v2.4.4.

## acl.ldif

```
dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcAccess
olcAccess: to attrs=userPassword by dn="cn=Manager,dc=ad,dc=pthl,dc=hk" write by anonymous auth by self write by * none
olcAccess: to dn.base="" by * read
olcAccess: to * by dn="cn=Manager,dc=ad,dc=pthl,dc=hk" write by * read
```

and then I run

```
 ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f acl.ldif
```

and I run

```
 ldapsearch -x -b ou=people,dc=ad,dc=pthl,dc=hk "(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=someone))" -h 172.16.234.11
```

which returns

```
# remove some lines
# .....

userPassword:: e1NTSEE1MTJ9MUpGdjcyd0w4aWJZRHd2eHpacVYyb1c4Q1p0Z0JrdDNpdWJDcU9
 pVjhmNVQ2QkgzWVNLQnVmNU03bnVwNFB2Q2NiaHR3UGcxOW51VitLMitaUk9WY2JLT0NOMDROWGlG
```

Answer (score 1):

After read official [docs](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/slapdconf2.html#cn=config), I found the root cause, ACL is database-specific, either add front or HDB one. I added them in the wrong place. :(

So the final configure of mine is

```
dn: olcDatabase=hdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcHdbConfig
olcDatabase: hdb
olcSuffix: dc=ad,dc=pthl,dc=hk
olcRootDN: cn=Manager,dc=ad,dc=pthl,dc=hk

#................
#................

# user itself and Manager write, anonymous bind, other deny
olcAccess: to attrs=userPassword
  by self write
  by anonymous auth
  by dn.base="cn=Manager,dc=ad,dc=pthl,dc=hk" write
  by * none
# Manager write, other(both authenticated and anonymous) read.
olcAccess: to *
  by dn.base="cn=Manager,dc=ad,dc=pthl,dc=hk" write
  by * read
```

And the default access control policy is allow read by all clients. Regardless of what access control policy is defined, the rootdn is always allowed full rights (i.e. auth, search, compare, read and write) on everything and anything.

As a consequence, it's useless (and results in a performance penalty) to explicitly list the rootdn among the  clauses.

Comment: Another useful link is [link] (https://serverfault.com/questions/325912/disallow-global-anonymous-bind-with-cn-config).